# Incompatible pointer to integer conversion sending 'NSIndexPath *__strong' to parameter of type 'NSUInteger' (aka 'unsigned long')

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

Can't seem to get rid of the warning at 3rd line. What is the problem here?

```
NSArray *arrayOfIndexPaths = [self.collectionView indexPathsForSelectedItems];
NSIndexPath *indexofAlbum = [arrayOfIndexPaths firstObject];
NSArray *sendImages = [image objectAtIndex:indexofAlbum];
```

Comment: `[image objectAtIndex:indexofAlbum.row];` or `[image objectAtIndex:indexofAlbum.section];`?

Comment: @Larme hmm. .. wil try

Comment: you need to learn to understand the error message, it tells you **everything** that you need to know

Answer (score 3):

`objectAtIndex` requires `NSInteger` value to be given with it. There is no natural conversion from `NSIndexPath` to `NSInteger`, instead you have to take one of the members of `NSIndexPath` and use it to access the data source. This is normally row. Try this

```
NSArray *sendImages = [image objectAtIndex:indexofAlbum.row];
```

Comment: Yeah, but you need to give a clue as to what the conversion means.

Comment: Sorry trojan I didin't get you

Comment: Well there is no natural conversion from `NSIndexPath` to `NSInteger`, instead you have to take one of the members of `NSIndexPath` and use it to access the data source. This is normally `row`.  This needs explaining.

Comment: There is nothing to be sorry for.

Answer (score 0):

objectAtIndex should follow NSInteger, you send a NSIndexPath to there.